# Load a properties inside a jar

Tags: maven, maven-3

Can I load a properties file inside a `jar` in a `maven plugin` execution?

I have a jar with a system-properties (among other things). I can download and expand it, but I wonder if I there is a way to configure a `maven` `plugin` (`maven jetty plugin`) to load these properties. I was thinking in the:

```
<configuration>
    <systemPropertiesFile></systemPropertiesFile>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll probably have to use [`dependency:unpack`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/unpacking-artifacts.html) first to write the properties to a temporary file, and then the [properties-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/properties-maven-plugin/) to read the properties from that file.

Comment: sounds sensible. If no one comes up with a more suitable answer I will accept this one. Thanks!